The error message of "Failed to fetch" for neo4j
When I used ":GET /rdf/neo4j/describe/358", an error message of "Failed to fetch" returned. 358 is a returned ID(p) by a query of "MATCH (p:Product) WHERE p.productName = "Queso Manchego La Pastora"". How can I resolve it?
Please give me your answers.
